# Trouble getting list box items to populate in C#

Tags: c#

I need to call an array to get following program working, but I can't figure it out. I'm not sure what is or isn't working, because I can't get the list box populate. Following is the code.

```
using System.IO;

namespace Test_Your_Knowledge__Game
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        string questionOne;
        string questionTwo;
        string questionThree;                  
        string firstQuestion = ("Who is a Silk Worm?");
        string secondQuestion = ("What does Sapience mean?");
        string thirdQuestion = ("What is Tainou?");
        string firstAnswer = ("Onycho");
        string secondAnswer = ("Wisdom");
        string thirdAnswer = ("A Wolf");
        int count = 0;


    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


  private void playButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

      string name;
      string email;


      name = nameTextBox.Text;
      email = emailTextBox.Text;

      StreamWriter outputFile;
      outputFile = File.CreateText("Submission_List.txt");

      outputFile.WriteLine(name);
      outputFile.WriteLine(email);
      outputFile.WriteLine(count);

      outputFile.Close();

  }

   private void myArray(string[] strArray, string value)
    {

        bool found = false;
        int index = 0;
        int position = -1;

        while (!found && index < strArray.Length)

            if (strArray[index] == value)
            {
                found = true;
                position = index;
                index++;
            }

        string[] questionOneArray = { "1) Beebo", "2) Bael", "3) Onycho", "4) Ilion" };
        string[] questionTwoArray = { "1) Beauty", "2) Cursed", "3) Properity", "4) Wisdom" };
        string[] questionThreeArray = { "1) Imp", "2) Wolf", "3) Trow", "4) Elf" };

        foreach (string length in strArray)

        {
            try
            {
                if (questionOneArray[index] != firstAnswer)
                {

                    questionOne = (firstQuestion + "" + questionOneArray);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(questionOne.ToString());
                    found = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    found = true;
                    count++;
                }


                {
                    if (questionTwoArray[index] != secondAnswer)
                    {
                        questionTwo = (secondQuestion + "" + questionTwoArray);
                        listBox1.Items.Add(questionTwo.ToString());
                        found = false;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        found = true;
                        count++;
                    }

                    {
                        if (questionThreeArray[index] != thirdAnswer)
                        {
                            questionThree = (thirdQuestion + "" + questionThreeArray);
                            listBox1.Items.Add(questionThree.ToString());
                            found = false;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            found = true;
                            count++;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) 
{ }
}
}
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to do. will need more information like What output you want, what are you getting and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm sorry.... I'm trying to write the question and arrays in a list box, so that the player can choose an answer. If it's right it will add one to the score that will be calculated at the end of answering the three questions and written to a file. The program runs, but I can't get anything to write to the list box.

Comment: You realize that step **one** is to put the questions and answers into arrays first. Right?

Comment: isn't that what I did with my if statements?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is use the `DataSource` property

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        string[] questions=new string[] {
            "Who is a Silk Worm?",
            "What does Sapience mean?",
            "What is Tainou?"
        };

        listBox1.DataSource=questions;
    }
}
```

[image: SCR]

Alternatively you can read a file

```
List<string> questions=new List<string>();
var fs=File.OpenText("<path to file with questions here>");
while (fs.EndOfStream)
{
    questions.Add(fs.ReadLine());
}
fs.Close();

listBox1.DataSource=questions;
```

Comment: We haven't learned base classes yet. I had a feeling that my program might require advanced code to work. Is there a way to do it using basic code?

Comment: Well at least I have something writing now. Thank you. I will manipulate it and get it to work. Appreciate your time.

Comment: You cannot do forms unless you understand inheritance and base classes. In this case, all you need to know is to place code that fills in values in a `OnLoad()` method which gets called automatically by the system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, 
i guess, you want a listbox of answers, then use the selected index int for your tests

Hence to load the box

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string[] questionOneArray = { "1) Beebo", "2) Bael", "3) Onycho", "4) Ilion" };
    ForEach (string s in questionOneArray)
    {
       ListBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Still not writing to the list box. I was told that the array has to be called before I write to file, so I'm assuming the answer is somewhere in there. How do I call myArray so the other arrays  write in a list box?

Comment: string[] questionOneArray move this to top. Then myArray(questionOneArray,"the-answer")